# nginx reverse proxy: How to implement?

Tags: configuration, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to do a reverse proxy with Nginx based on the URL. I want `http://mydomain.example.com/client1/...` to be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8193/...`. I have tried many ways, and none of them worked. Please note that the application can make redirections. These are the configuration files of my last solution :

### default

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             mydomain.example.com;

    location / {
            set $instance none;
            if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)/$) {
                    set $instance $1;
            }

            set $no_cookie true;
            if ($http_cookie ~ "instance=([^;] +)(?:;|$)") {
                    set $instance $1;
                    set $no_cookie false;
            }

            if ($no_cookie = true) {
                    add_header Set-Cookie "instance=$instance;Domain=$host;Path=/";
                    rewrite ^ / break;
            }

            include instances.conf;
    }
```

### instances.conf

```
proxy_redirect                 off;
proxy_set_header               Host $host;
proxy_set_header               X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header               X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_connect_timeout          90;
proxy_send_timeout             60;

# Installation of language packs, etc. can take a long time
proxy_read_timeout             10800;

if ($instance = client1) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8193;
}

if ($instance = client2) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8194
}

...
```

When the browser requests `http://mydomain.example.com/client1/`, Nginx should set a cookie named `instance` with the value `client1` then redirect the traffic to the appropriate proxy. For subsequent queries, it should use this cookie to make redirection. The problem I have is it never sets the `$instance` variable to `client1`. Don't forget that the application has no idea of the prefix `/client1`.

Do you have an idea? Do you know of a better solution?

Comment: I think the problem is with the regex used to get the cookie value. I'm not an expert on regex. I took this from Nginx's documentation file. Can someone validate this ?

Answer (score 1):

The regex used to get the cookie was wrong. I have changed this to

```
"instance=([^;][^ ]+)(?:;|$)"
```

and it works now.

Edit: It's only a part of the solution finally. I'm sorry. There is still a problem. See my comment below.

Comment: Nope... it has worked because I've forced a value to proxy_pass. But now when I manually set the cookie into Firefox, it works ! There is a problem when it should set the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to your problem but "proxy_connect_timeout"

"This directive assigns a timeout for the connection to the upstream server. It is necessary to keep in mind that this time out cannot be more than 75 seconds."

Comment: why is this relevant?

Answer (score -1):

See Nginx' [map module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule)

```
map $uri $proxy {
    /client1     http://127.0.0.1:8193/client1;
    /client2     http://127.0.0.1:8194/client2;
}

server {
    server_name my.domain.com;
    proxy_pass $proxy;
}
```

Note that appending /clientX to the end of the proxy_pass URI strips that portion of the URI from the request (which seems rational to me, but may not be what you want).

Comment: proxy_pass cannot be in the server directive.